# How to change background color of editText?

Tags: java, android

I need to change background color of `EditText` if it is empty.
Below is my code but doesn't seem to be working.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub            
    Change();    
}

public void Change() {
    if(("").equals(name)) {
        name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to check the length:

```
if (name.length() == 0) {
    name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: @artist Glad to hear it. Please mark the accept the answer which you choice (the checkbox outline to the left). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming 'name' is the EditText in question, your if statement should read something like this:

```
if(("").equals(name.getText().toString()))
```

Performing an Object.equals(Object) between a String and an EditText (at least currently!) will not return true.

Comment: I wanted to indicate where the mistake was made.  Thanks!

Comment: I should have mentioned that your solution definitely works and does better show where the error was, whereas I wanted to indicate the best way to check if an EditText is empty. Clearly they're both correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = nameedittext.getText().toString();

if(name.isEmpty()){
    nameedittext.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

If you want to give a error message too then you can write this:

```
if(name.isEmpty()){
    nameedittext.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    nameedittext.setError("Please Enter Name");
    return;
}
```

Comment: *name* is instance of *EditText*, so it does not contain *isEmpty* method.

Comment: that was my mistake.  It is edited now.